# SUM function in Pig script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hortonworks-data-platform

I am a student learning how to use Pig script using the hortonworks sandbox.  My problem is that I am not able to use the `SUM` function properly.  I have successfully separated the fields of a firewall log and I am able to do perform several queries and use the count function... but no luck with the `SUM` function which I really need in one case.  This code I used below:

```
A = FOREACH logs_base GENERATE device_id,src,src_port,dst,dst_port,tran_ip,tran_port,service,duration,sent,rcvd,sent_pkt,rcvd_pkt,SN,user,group1, REGEX_EXTRACT(date, '\\d{3}-(\\d{2})-\\d{2}', 1) AS(month:chararray);
F1 = FILTER A BY user == 'PR11MS1120' and month == '10';
grpd1 = group F1 by user;
counter = foreach grpd1 {
    sum1 = SUM(A.rcvd);
    sum2 = SUM(A.sent);
    generate sum1, sum2;
};
dump counter;
C = foreach F1 generate rcvd, sent;
dump C;
```

When I dump just the variable `C` I get a result displaying many records indicating the amount of data received/sent for the filter applied. eg:

```
(223,123)
(334,444)
(21,12344)
(...,...)
```

All I really want to do is add all those records together and show that total amount of received and sent: `(?,?)`.

Note:  I have tried changing the variable type to `int`, `long`, and `chararray` with no success either.

Some of the errors I am getting while trying to solve this are:

> Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.SUM as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.

Answer (score 1):

A lucky guess here, I'm new to Pig too :)
I'm not sure if SUM can be casted to chararray(that would explain the error), so make rcvd and sent type:`int` and then generate the 2 sums for grpd1 bag:

```
 F1 = FILTER A BY user == 'PR11MS1120' and month == '10';
    grpd1 = group F1 by user; 
    C1 = foreach grpd1 generate SUM(F1.rcvd);
    dump C1;
    C2 = foreach grpd1 generate SUM(F1.sent);
    dump C2;
```

**NOTE**: More info [here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#sum).

Hope I helped a little!

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that the fields that you are summing up are of type int

Use - `DESCRIBE A;` to check the data type
After that, I think since you have used filter condition and then used group by on F1 -

```
F1 = FILTER A BY user == 'PR11MS1120' and month == '10';
grpd1 = group F1 by user;
```

So, while summing up you should use F1 instead of A -

```
counter = foreach grpd1 {
    sum1 = SUM(F1.rcvd);
    sum2 = SUM(F1.sent);
    generate sum1, sum2;
};
```

Use `DESCRIBE grpd1;` and you will understand what I am trying to say, there will be no 'A'
I guess this should solve the error. Finally, check the logic of what you want in the result I have not checked that. Hope this helps.
PS - I am also a student and new to PIG.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

```
A = FOREACH logs_base GENERATE device_id,src,src_port,dst,dst_port,tran_ip,tran_port,service,duration,sent,rcvd,sent_pkt,rcvd_pkt,SN,user,group1, REGEX_EXTRACT(date, '\\d{3}-(\\d{2})-\\d{2}', 1) AS(month:chararray);
F1 = FILTER A BY user == 'PR11MS1120' and month == '10';
grpd1 = group F1 by user;
C = foreach F1 generate group,SUM(F1.rcvd), SUM(F1.sent);
dump C;
```